# How to transform data to better see points on graph (at 0,0)

Tags: r, plot, graph, transform

[image]

I'm trying to plot a graph in r to show different abundances in blood and tissue samples. (i.e coloured if something is present in blood (blue) or tissue (green) or both (black).

However, this means the points in blue are along the (x,0) line as they have no abundance in tissue and vice versa. Is there a way I could transform my data to spread out the points more so that I could see them better on the graph?

The code I used was:

`plot(data$x, data$y, col=data$sample_colour, xlab="Blood", ylab="Tissue")`

Comment: What is the code you used ? It seems first you will have to reduce your y axis interval

Comment: I've updated the post with the code I used, and reduced the y axis

Comment: You could do a log transformation and plot on log scale. Are you replacing "<MDL" with "0" in your data? . Not sure what the convention is in blood work, but in water quality work we replace "<MDL" with half of the MDL, resulting in no values of zero concentration. Also - if your data has concentrations of "0" you may have to go back to the lab and ask them what the MDL is for that particular method.

Comment: Note that in my comment I'm assuming the lab uses Method Detection Limit (MDL). They might use other conventions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detection_limit

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this to facet the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(blood = runif(100),
                 tissue = runif(100),
                 color = 0)

zeros <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
df$blood <- df$blood * zeros
zeros <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
df$tissue <- df$tissue * zeros

df$color <- ifelse(df$tissue == 0 & df$blood > 0, "blood only",
                   ifelse(df$tissue > 0 & df$blood == 0, "tissue only", "both"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = tissue, y = blood)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = color)) +
    facet_grid(~color)
```

[image]